# mongoose schema default property is not updating

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm saving timeStamp when mongoose created document.

My problem is that timeStamp is not changing properly.
Whenever I save the document, `createdAt` returns the moment when server has started.

mongoose model to save timeStamp (using `createdAt` property)

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

const requestSchema = new Schema({
  createdAt: {
    type: String,
    default: moment
      .tz(new Date(), 'Asia/Seoul')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
  },
  ...
})
```

And I'm creating mongodb document in function like below

```
export const returnRecordObject = async (arg) => {
  const recordObject = { type: 'record' }
  const savedRecord = await models.Request.create(recordObject);
  if(savedRecord) {
    return savedRecord;
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

It seems that `new Date()` is not called at every `create` call of mongoose.
I'm not that familiar to mongoose, so I couldn't find any APIs.

To summarize,

1) How can I make mongoose's default to be updated on every `create` or other function call?

2) Would it be better to explicitly assign `createdAt` property before `create` of mongoose? For example, code like below is better than above?

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const requestSchema = new Schema({
  // Remove createdAt property
  ...
})
```

```
export const returnRecordObject = async (arg) => {
  const recordObject = { type: 'record', createdAt: moment
      .tz(new Date(), 'Asia/Seoul')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}
  const savedRecord = await models.Request.create(recordObject);
  if(savedRecord) {
    return savedRecord;
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I also needed to control the default function, and found [this documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions-and-this). Commented for anyone who is looking more feature in default function at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a value to `default` that mean the default is value of `moment.tz(new Date(), 'Asia/Seoul').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` when this line of code run. To make it work as you expected, you need to pass in a function that return `moment.tz(new Date(), 'Asia/Seoul').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`. Something like:

```
default: function() {
  return moment.tz(new Date(), 'Asia/Seoul').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
}...
```

You can read more: [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions)